# nested ng-mouseover in angularjs doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I used the same approach with jquery which is the nested mouseover and mouseleave and it worked, but not with angularjs.

I want to show the button when mouseenter into the `<li>`, but hide the button when the mouse touched the `<p>`. But the problem is my `<p>` is within the `<li>`.

```
<li ng-mouseover="showXBtn=true" ng-mouseleave="showXBtn=false">
  <p ng-mouseover="showXBtn=false" ng-mouseleave="showXBtn=true">Hide</p>

  <button ng-show="showXBtn"><span>x</span></button>
</li>
```

demo here : http://plnkr.co/edit/66fxwmAJ3EZgpZql1yLP?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stop the propagation of the event from `p`

```
<p ng-mouseover="showXBtn=false; $event.stopPropagation()" ng-mouseleave="showXBtn=true; test($event)">Hide</p>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dMTc2/)

---

Otherwise use mouseenter instead of mouseout

```
<li ng-mouseenter="showXBtn=true; test($event)" ng-mouseleave="showXBtn=false; test($event)">
    <p ng-mouseenter="showXBtn=false;" ng-mouseleave="showXBtn=true; test($event)">Hide</p>
    <button ng-show="showXBtn"><span>x</span></button>
</li>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dMTc2/3/)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `ng-mouseenter` instead of `ng-mouseover`. [Updated PLUNK](http://plnkr.co/edit/orYf6t6jp31oDy4cINYQ?p=preview)